# Enable mouse wheel autoscroll feature in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, mouse, macos

Is it possible to enable autoscroll (scrolling on mouse wheel press) in mac os? In windows it works out of the box, in mac id does not. Macos 10.6.8, Chrome v21

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's an extension called [AutoScroll](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/occjjkgifpmdgodlplnacmkejpdionan) that enables scrolling while pressing a middle button.

You can also enable it everywhere in OS X with [Smart Scroll](http://marcmoini.com/sx_en.html). See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/303424/can-i-enable-scrolling-with-middle-button-drag-in-os-x).

To make middle clicking work with a Magic Mouse, you'd also need to install an application like [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net) or [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com).

Answer (score 6):

[Smooze](https://smooze.co) offers that, among other things. (I'm the developer)

Also, upon releasing the Auto Scroll, the scroll will continue to animate just like the iPhone scroll works. (this of course can be configured or turned off)

[image]